# Loading Multiple Xib View in one cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, xib, custom-cell

My tableview has 3layer

first: Header

second: section

third: xibviews

My tableviewCell load Xibs view depend on indexPath.row

For example indexPath.row is at 2 , i want to load CDFlightXibView

But it makes it **too slow** when scrolling

What should i do ?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        print("contract detail")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let vieww = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CDContractXibView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CDContractXibFile

        vieww?.fillData()

        cell.contentView.addSubview(vieww!)
        vieww?.frame = cell.contentView.frame
        vieww?.center = cell.contentView.center


        return cell
    case 1:
        print("passenger")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let vieww = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CDPassengerInFlightXibView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CDPassengerInFlightXibFile

        vieww?.fillData()

        cell.contentView.addSubview(vieww!)
        vieww?.frame = cell.contentView.frame
        vieww?.center = cell.contentView.center


        return cell
    case 2:
        print("flight")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let vieww = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CDFlightXibView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CDFlightXibFile

        vieww?.fillData()
        vieww?.detailBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showPassenger(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        vieww?.detailBtn.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.contentView.addSubview(vieww!)
        vieww?.frame = cell.contentView.frame
        vieww?.center = cell.contentView.center


        return cell

    default:
        print("nothing")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading multiple xib files every time you scroll and all this actions need computations that cause laggy scroll.

Try design specific UITableViewCell for each state and dequeue them by indexPath.section cases.

Comment: i dequeue the mainArray with indexPath.section for header , and dequeue subArray with indexPath.row for each header

Comment: I mean that for example for "contract detail", create a UITableViewCell called "CDContractTableViewCell" and put "CDContractXibView" in its xib file instead, then in cellForRow method, when indexPath.section equals 1, use this:
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contractCell", for: indexPath) as! CDContractTableViewCell`